# Unable to connect to SQL Server on Windows 10 and using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to connect to a database in SQL Server 2014.

Visual Studio does pick up the database as shown in the screenshot here:

[image: VisualStudioPickup]

The connection string is as follows:

[image: ConnectionString]

The code is:

```
const string connString = "Data Source=CLEAVEN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EduAssistR;Integrated Security=True";
```

But I still get error 26 in the browser:

[image]

I've restarted the SQL Server Browser and enable TCP and Remote connections but I still get the error.

If I use `CLEAVEN\SQLEXPRESS` instead of `CLEAVEN\\SQLEXPRESS`, I get this error:

[image: oneslash]

What could be wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are your Web settings in your project?  Are you using local IIS?

Comment: have you tried useing ip address instead of using the server name?

Comment: Can be that issue with this "CLEAVEN\\SQLEXPRESS". Normally, named instances have single slash: "CLEAVEN\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: @AlexanderVolok I've updated my question to answer your comment

Comment: @squillman yes using local IIS but it will be deployed onto an actual server later in the year

Comment: @Lester I have never tried that, would you just replace the connection string with an ip address

Comment: Try using a verbatim string as to rule out any escaping issues, and change the server name to a dot. `@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;..."`. A single backslash needs to be escaped on Windows regardless though.

Comment: @alexander The debugger adds the double slash automatically during display

Comment: @Cleaven when you enabled tcp you also restarted sql service? Also, it can be caused simply by firewall. If you stopped  it do you still have the issue?

Comment: You're trying to connect to a SQLEXPRESS instance running under your local user account. Are you sure it's running there and not under the machine account? (hence the dot)

Comment: @Cleaven Sorry, I was meaning are you using Local IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: @Cleaven, can you access your database from SQL server management studio?

Comment: Laptop has other name that cleaven. Can you try to replace cleaven with a real laptop name?

Comment: try this: const string connString = "Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog= ....  replace the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to the sql-server ip

Comment: @Emdad Yes I can

Comment: @squillman I'm not sure, where can I find out?

Comment: @FredKleuver Yes i did restart, and firewall is off

Comment: @AlexanderVolok would that be local service or local system

Comment: @Cleaven look at your project properties, there is a Web section.  It'll have options for Local IIS or IIS Express.  If you don't remember setting it it's probably IIS Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong.

Silly silly mistake.

In the Web.config

I did not change my connection string. Once I changed it there, all was solved.

Thank you to everyone